# Unable to replace to "||" using replaceAll method

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I want to replace Or, or, OR, oR to  "||"

```
validationExpr = validationExpr.replaceAll('(?i)or', ' \\|\\| ');
```

The result will be `&#124;&#124;`

How could we do this in Apex?
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get || or &#124;&#124;?

Comment: What behavior do you observe, and how does it diverge from  your expected behavior?

Comment: the below response answered my question. thank  you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will get `&#124;&#124;` in debug log because Salesforce uses `|`character as a separator in debug logs however in real time application, it will work as expected.

Example:

```
20:59:52.14 (15076267)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
20:59:52.14 (15083284)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2]|Bytes:6
20:59:52.14 (15087825)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2]|Bytes:6
20:59:52.14 (15149679)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2]|Bytes:12
20:59:52.14 (15167781)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[2]|validationExpr|"hey  &#124;&#124;  hey"
```

I created a sample VF pg to test this:

VF page code:

```
<apex:page controller="TestClass">
    {!strData}
    <hr/>
    {!strData2}
</apex:page>
```

Class Code:

```
public class TestClass {
    public String strData{get;set;}
    public String strData2{get;set;}

    public TestClass(){
        strData = '||';
        strData2 = 'Hello or Hi OR Hola'.replaceAll('(?i)or', ' \\|\\| ');
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]